# Smooth scrolling in Delphi

Tags: delphi, smooth-scrolling

For years I have been using smooth-scrolling plugins in my browsers (firefox/chrome).

They give a precise feel both for the eye and for navigating.
No line by line flickering.

Is this functionality possible in the Delphi editor ?
Or for that matter in any of the VCL controls TMemo/TStringGrid/TTreeView etc ?

I know that in TVirtualTreeView it is possible to scroll by pixels.

Comment: The `TMemo` and `TTreeView` are native Windows controls, while the `TStringGrid` is a custom control written in Delphi.

Comment: @LU RD, good question; anyway, you can scroll by pixels using [TWinControl.ScrollBy](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Controls.TWinControl.ScrollBy) function (don't know from which Delphi version). The hard part is to "override" standard functionality but I guess someone has it.

Comment: I almost upvoted you purely for my discovery of the SmoothScroll plugin for Chrome. Almost.

Comment: @Ciaran, once you get spoiled with the feeling of a smooth scroll, it's hard to accept anything else.

Comment: Yes, I think I hate you for this.

Answer (score 0):

The RichView package offers some options that you may like such as `TRichView`. Also, with XE2 you can set items to be Double Buffered `ExampleItem.DoubleBuffered := True;` which helps smooth things out.

Comment: The RichView components does not support vertical scrolling by pixels. The smallest scrolling unit is 10 pixels. So sorry, this is not what I am looking for. The [RichView](http://www.trichview.com/) component set seems competent for lots of other things though.